# in PHP, how to add a tag within an existing one?

Tags: php

I'm trying to add a `<style>` tag within an existing `<head>` tag.  I can't seem to figure out how to do this for some reason; this is what I've come up with so far (by the way, the existing `<head>` tag is empty):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($htmlfile_data);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$headnode = $xpath->query('//head'); // i assume this is an array?
$stylenode = $dom->createElement('style');
$headnode[0]->appendChild($stylenode);

$htmlfile_data = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Basically I want the output to be:

before:

```
<head></head>
```

after:

```
<head><style></style></head>
```

Comment: Note that `$dom->getElementsByTagName('head')` would be significantly (~3x) faster than using XPath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$headnode` is a [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) object, which can't be used like an array. Instead, do this:

```
$headnode->item(0)->appendChild($node);
```

You can use `var_dump($headnode)` to see its type.